# How do I center left-justified text?

Tags: css

Here's the ugly code that works:

```
<table style="margin: auto"><tr><td>
Name: Fred Flintstone<br>
Home: Bedrock<br>
Favorite activity: Going to the drive-in and eating a brontosaurus burger!
</td></tr></table>
```

My goal is to center a block of left-justified text.  The only way that I know how to do it at this point is to try to measure/guess the width of the necessary containing div.  "Ok, maybe 400px.  No, that causes it to wrap...  Let's try 450."

What I really need is some code to create a container that will allow me to put any text within it and have it resize itself to that width.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use some `<div>` containers as follows ([example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3bWh/)):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      Name: Fred Flintstone<br>
      Home: Bedrock<br>
      Favorite activity: Going to the drive-in and eating a brontosaurus burger!
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
}

#content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Awww, beat me to this. but yah, inline-block sound exactly what you need.